# Change number format by adding decimal to it in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a number 000005500 and I want it to be in format 0000055.00 or 55.00 using an Oracle select query.

I used this query:

```
select to_char(to_number(000005500),'99.99') from dual
```

but its displaying `#####`

How can I display it in the format I need?

Comment: # means that the format is smaller than the actual number wanting to be displayed. Some functions, like this one, really doesn't assume anything, and needs every POTENTIAL digit to be defined. If your table wouldn't hold a line with value 5500, it may not have given any error. To cover that : what is the maximum number of digits of the STORAGE data type ? Have the format be that, AT MINIMUM. The example shown has 9 digits (before the comma), and your format has 2. Two is less than nine, so that's an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written your `to_number()` call is just doing an implicit conversion to a string and then an explicit conversion back to a number, which seems pointless, but I assume you're actually dealing with a value from a `varchar2` column. In which case you see:

```
select to_char(to_number('000005500'),'99.99') from dual

TO_CHA
------
######
```

You're seeing the hashes because you can't fit your four-digit number, 5500, into a 99.99 format - you have four digits before the decimal point and the format mask only allows for two.

The bit you seem to be missing is dividing by 100 to get the decimal:

```
select to_char(to_number('000005500') / 100,'99.99') from dual;

TO_CHA
------
 55.00
```

Another approach, if you want to keep it as a string with the same number of leading zeros as the oroginal value, is to leave it as a string, chop it up with `substr()`, and concatenate the parts back together. Using a CTE as a demo:

```
with t as (select '000005500' as val from dual)
select val, substr(val, 1, length(val) - 2)
  || '.' || substr(val, length(val) - 1, 2) as adj_val
from t;

 VAL       ADJ_VAL
--------- ---------------------------------------------
000005500 0000055.00
```

Comment: *dividing by 100 to get the decimal* Nice and easy!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `000005500` is not a number. A number doesn't start with zero. You are dealing with a string.

> I want it to be in format 0000055.00

You can only expect it to be a string as an output, and not a number.

Anyway, to get the output as `55.00` as NUMBER, you could do the following -

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT '000005500' num FROM DUAL
  3  )
  4  SELECT to_char(to_number(replace(num,'0','')),'99D99') FROM DATA
  5  /

TO_CHA
------
 55.00

SQL>
```

Or,

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT '000005500' num FROM DUAL
  3  )
  4  SELECT to_char(to_number(rtrim(ltrim(num,'0'),'0')),'99D99') FROM DATA
  5  /

TO_CHA
------
 55.00

SQL>
```

**Edit**

Alex's method is also nice, it uses simple mathematics to convert it to DECIMAL. I would prefer his way for the first part.

Comment: Those both only works if the last two digits in the original are zeros; if the value was, say, '000005501', then it would still not match the format?

Comment: Yes, I just gave specific answer to OP. It can't be generalized.

Answer (score 0):

Another couple of alternatives around the final formatting:

```
select to_char(to_number('000005500')/100,'0999999D90') leading_zeros,
       to_char(to_number('000005500')/100,'fm9999999D90') no_leading_zeros
from dual;
```